# How to quickly separate and/or delete extra faces created by extruding?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have made a giant plane and subdivided it with 100 cuts. I am extruding the surfaces to make a "room" if you will.

[image: Blender Screen Shot]

If the areas are not extruded in the same extrusion, a wall is left between the two extrusions, as you can see at the end of the green arrow.

What I would like to do is take one of the "squares" on these said walls and delete it. Now I had tried to work around this by grabbing the wall at the top and pulling down on it but the problem with that is it is connected to the walls next to it. So when it moves they move.

#### Question

Is there a way to delete one specific "square" from a plane or one specific side to a cube? Also, is there a way to 'unhook' or 'unbind' the objects or squares of a plan from one another when scaling or skewing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Blender, skippy. There are multiple ways to achieve what you want in Blender, and some are more appropriate in one situation, and others work better in different situations. But the nature of your question suggests to me that you would be well served to visit the answers on learning in [question 15355](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/) with special attention to the entry under "learning", online courses.

Comment: In edge mode, you can delete a face by deleting one of the edges of the face, in other words if you delete the edge you tried to move down, it deletes the face. As as unhooking, on the left side of your screen shot under the word "Add" in the toolshelf, the third item down is "Extrude individual". This extrudes the individual vertices (and I assume, individual edges and faces, too.

Comment: @SKIPPY, ask a new separate question please. The purpose of this site is to have questions which can be dealt with as one concept, so they can be searched and found with meaningful titles. blender stackexchange is not a forum for a continued discussion about unrelated questions. Feel free to ask as many separate question "threads" as you want.

Comment: @Skippy. Please don't add additional questions in the original post.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I saw saving some clutter space. I'm used to forums. I will delete it and ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

By now you are working with "edge" selection mode (2nd button on the header).

Just switch to "faces" mode (the third), select the face you want to delete, press <kbd>X</kbd> and choose the preferred option.

Try also the first button (vertex mode).

The fourth on the right lets you also select  vertex, edges or faces hidden by some other geometry.

[image]

Another useful function is select some faces, hit <kbd>P</kbd>*> Selection*, then exit edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>). The selected faces will be no longer be a part of your original object: they are a brand new object.

Additionally if you hit <kbd>Y</kbd> instead of <kbd>P</kbd> the selection will be separated from the original mesh while remaining part of the same object.